# JS - Error: "Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, genetic-algorithm, p5.js, codepen

I'm attempting to make a genetic algorithm simulation in JavaScript using the P5.JS library, but i'm experiencing some issues. Here's what i have so far:

```js
//var popS = 2;
var popu;
//var balls = [];
var target;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 300);
  popu = new Population();
  target = createVector(width - 15, height / 2);
}

function draw() {
  background(50);
  popu.run();

  var ballsC = 0;
  for (var a = 0; a < popu.balls.length; a++) {
    if (popu.balls[a].done == true){ 
      ballsC ++;
    }
  }
  if (ballsC >= popu.popS) {
    //popu = new Population();
    popu.evaluate();
    //popu.selection();
  }

  fill(255, 0, 30);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(target.x, target.y, 20, 20);
}

function DNA() {
  this.genes = [];
  this.changes = 7;//random(2, 50);

  for (var a = 0; a < this.changes; a++) {
    this.genes[a] = random(0, 15);
  }

  this.crossover = function (pB) {
    var newdna = new DNA();
    var mid = floor(random(0, this.genes.length));
    for (var a = 0; a < this.genes.length; a++) {
      if (a < mid) {
        newdna.genes[a] = this.genes[a];
      }else {
        newdna.genes[a] = pB.genes[a];
      }
    }
    return newdna;
  }
}

function Population() {
  this.balls = [];
  this.popS = 50;
  this.maxfit = 0;
  this.matingpool = [];

  for (var a = 0; a < this.popS; a++) {
    this.balls[a] = new Ball();
  }

  this.evaluate = function() {
    for (var a = 0; a < this.balls.length; a++) {
      this.balls[a].calcF();
      if (this.balls[a].fitness > this.maxfit) {
        this.maxfit = this.balls[a].fitness;
      }
    }
    this.matingpool = [];
    for (var b = 0; b < this.balls.length; b++) {
      var n = this.balls[b].fitness * 100;
      for (var c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        this.matingpool.push(this.balls[c]);
      }
    }

    this.selection();
  }

  this.selection = function () {
    var newBalls = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < this.balls.length; a++) {
      var parentA = this.matingpool[floor(random(0, this.matingpool.length))];
      var parentB = this.matingpool[floor(random(0, this.matingpool.length))];
      var child = parentA.dna.crossover(parentB.dna);
      newBalls[a] = new Ball(child);
    }
    this.balls = newBalls;
  }

  this.run = function() {
    for (var a = 0; a < this.balls.length; a++) {
      this.balls[a].update();
      this.balls[a].checkCol();
      this.balls[a].show();
    }
  }
}

function Ball(dna) {
  this.pos = createVector(10, height / 2);
  this.speed = createVector(2, 2.5);
  this.mul = -1;
  this.time = 0;
  this.a = 0;
  if (dna) {
    this.dna = dna;
  } else {
    this.dna = new DNA();
  }
  this.done = false;
  this.fitness = 0;
  this.reached;

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.done == false) {
      if (this.time >= this.dna.genes[this.a]) {
        this.a++;
        this.time = 0;
        this.mul *= -1;
      }
      this.speed.set(2, 2.5 * this.mul);
      this.pos.add(this.speed);
    }
  }

  this.show = function() {
    this.time += 0.1;
    fill(255, 70);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, 10, 10);
  }

  this.checkCol = function() {
    if (this.pos.y > height || this.pos.y < 0 || this.pos.x > width) {
      //print("col");
      this.done = true;
    }
    if (dist(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, target.x, target.y) <= (10 / 2) + (20 / 2)) {
      //print("done!");
      this.done = true;
      this.reached = true;
    }
  }

  this.calcF = function() {
    var a = dist(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, target.x, target.y);
    var b = this.dna.genes.length;
    var c = 0;
    if (this.reached){
      c = 1;
    }

    this.fitness = map(map(a, 0, width, 1, 0) + map(b, 2, 50, 1, 0) + c, 0, 3, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

This is the most essential part of the code:

```js
var popu;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 300);
  popu = new Population();
}

function draw() {
  background(50);
  //popu = new Population();
  popu.evaluate();
  //popu.selection();
}

function DNA() {
  this.genes = [];
  this.changes = 7; //random(2, 50);

  for (var a = 0; a < this.changes; a++) {
    this.genes[a] = random(0, 15);
  }

  this.crossover = function(pB) {
    var newdna = new DNA();
    var mid = floor(random(0, this.genes.length));
    for (var a = 0; a < this.genes.length; a++) {
      if (a < mid) {
        newdna.genes[a] = this.genes[a];
      } else {
        newdna.genes[a] = pB.genes[a];
      }
    }
    return newdna;
  }
}

function Population() {
  this.balls = [];
  this.popS = 50;
  this.maxfit = 0;
  this.matingpool = [];

  for (var a = 0; a < this.popS; a++) {
    this.balls[a] = new Ball();
  }

  this.evaluate = function() {
    this.matingpool = [];
    for (var b = 0; b < this.balls.length; b++) {
      var n = this.balls[b].fitness * 100;
      for (var c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        this.matingpool.push(this.balls[c]);
      }
    }

    this.selection();
  }

  this.selection = function() {
    var newBalls = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < this.balls.length; a++) {
      var parentA = this.matingpool[floor(random(0, this.matingpool.length))];
      var parentB = this.matingpool[floor(random(0, this.matingpool.length))];
      var child = parentA.dna.crossover(parentB.dna);
      newBalls[a] = new Ball(child);
    }
    this.balls = newBalls;
  }
}

function Ball(dna) {
  this.pos = createVector(10, height / 2);
  this.speed = createVector(2, 2.5);
  this.mul = -1;
  this.time = 0;
  this.a = 0;
  if (dna) {
    this.dna = dna;
  } else {
    this.dna = new DNA();
  }
  this.done = false;
  this.fitness = 0;
  this.reached;

}
```

So whenever it gets to here:

```js
this.selection = function () {
    var newBalls = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < this.balls.length; a++) {
      var parentA = random(this.matingpool);
      var parentB = random(this.matingpool);
      var child = parentA.dna.crossover(parentB.dna);
      newBalls[a] = new Ball(child);
    }
    this.balls = newBalls;
  }
```

i get the error: "Cannot read property 'dna' of undefined", why on earth is this happening?? When i use the debugger in chrome i can clearly see that matingpool has 2000 elements but when i try to get a random one it returns "undefined".

```js
var parentA = random(this.matingpool);
var parentB = random(this.matingpool);
```

The weird thing is that parentB works, but parentA dosn't.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Entire code running here: http://codepen.io/felipe_mare/pen/bgOYMN

If it helps, i sometimes get the error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" instead, at line 138

```js
this.update = function() {
    if (this.done == false) {
      //line 138
      if (this.time >= this.dna.genes[this.a]) {
      //line 138
        this.a++;
        this.time = 0;
        this.mul *= -1;
      }
      this.speed.set(2, 2.5 * this.mul);
      this.pos.add(this.speed);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does your `random()` look?

Comment: @JohanP Please notice the [tag:p5.js] tag. The P5.js library provides the `random()` function.

Comment: Which line is "line 138"?

Comment: @AndrewLi `if (this.time >= this.dna.genes[this.a]) {` ill edit it, sorry for that

Comment: Any chance you can narrow this down to a [mcve] instead of your entire sketch? A more basic example with just a couple objects would be much easier to debug.

Comment: @KevinWorkman edited my answer the best i could

Comment: You don't ever seem to do anything with the `child` variable. What is its purpose?

Comment: Must have changed it while debugging, though it doesnt make any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future, please please please try to narrow your questions down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I understand that this was a complicated problem to debug, but you'll have much better luck if you try to narrow your problem down to a **minimal** (under 20 lines) example. Most of the time, you'll end up finding your error in the process of creating the MCVE.

But your problem is actually when you create the `matingpool` array, here:

```
this.matingpool = [];
for (var b = 0; b < this.balls.length; b++) {
  var n = this.balls[b].fitness * 100;
  for (var c = 0; c < n; c++) {
    this.matingpool.push(this.balls[c]);
  }
}
```

If I add a print statement inside the inner `for` loop, like this:

```
this.matingpool = [];
for (var b = 0; b < this.balls.length; b++) {
  var n = this.balls[b].fitness * 100;
  for (var c = 0; c < n; c++) {
    console.log("pushing: " + this.balls[c]);
    this.matingpool.push(this.balls[c]);
  }
}
```

Then I see that you're pushing `undefined` into the array a bunch of times:

```
(1178) pushing: [object Object]
(3) pushing: undefined
(482) pushing: [object Object]
(3) pushing: undefined
(216) pushing: [object Object]
```

Then you choose randomly from this array, which is why your error shows up in random places in your code.

You're going to have to debug this further to figure out why that's happening- it seems weird that you're looping based on a fitness instead of an array length, but I don't really understand the code well enough to be sure. In any case, hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: When you give it an array it returns a random element

Comment: @Pepe Oh wow. Never knew that. Neat. I'll keep digging and edit my answer when I figure it out.

Comment: i have also tried `this.matingpool[floor(random(0, this.matingpool.length))];` and it still doesnt work

Comment: Yeah thats it, should have been `this.matingpool.push(this.balls[b]);`. Still getting the "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" though, guess ill have to look into it even further. Thanks a lot for your help, have a nice day.

Comment: Yay its working! check it out: http://codepen.io/felipe_mare/pen/bgOYMN And thanks again for ur help!!